# Format value of form field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cakephp

I have an edit form which is populated from its corresponding model. It has a text field that has a date value associated with it. I am using a JavaScript plugin that allows the user to select a date from a popup, which shows it nicely in the field something like `July 15, 2015` but the plugin actually submits a hidden field with the format my database is expecting.

When I go to the edit page that field is pre-populated with the ugly date format value and the plugin doesn't update the format of the date when it's initialized, only when the user picks a date. Is there a way in cakephp I can pre-format that value before it's displayed to the page? Even if I ran it through a JavaScript plugin to handle the format that would be great.

My form field

```
echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'class' => 'pickadate',
    'placeholder' => 'Pick Date',
    'required' => true
));
```

The plugin I'm using is http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

```
$('.pickadate').pickadate
    format: 'mmmm dd, yyyy'
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    hiddenName: true
    container: 'main'
```

**UPDATE**

In being pointed to using a controller to format the value before it's passed to the view here is my controller code as I'm not sure where to do that

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {
    if (!$this->Meeting->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid meeting');
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Meeting->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The meeting has been saved.','default',array('class'=>'success'),'flash');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The meeting could not be saved. Please, try again.','default',array('class'=>'error'),'flash');
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Meeting->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Meeting.id' => $id,
            ),
        ));
    }
    $this->Meeting->set('date', CakeTime::format($this->Meeting->date, '%B %d, %Y'));
    $meetingRooms = $this->Meeting->MeetingRoom->find('list');
    $users = $this->Meeting->User->find('list');
    $events = $this->Meeting->Event->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('meetingRooms', 'users', 'events'));
}
```

Comment: can we see what youve tried? some code maybe?

Comment: You can use `helper` for that. Or may be set the format before or after fetching them.

Comment: @b0s3 I thought about that but I'm not sure where to do that? Do I need to do it in the controller for the edit action so it gets passed to the view? Or can I do this in the view somehow when I call the input method?

Comment: Yes. Use the controller action.

Comment: @b0s3 I've added the code for the edit controller action that I have, near the bottom before setting the view variables you can see what I've tried already but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I'm just a little confused as to how to get and set data in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I'm setting the data in `$this->request->data` which is being sent to the view, so I changed my code that updates the date to this

```
$this->request->data['Meeting']['date'] = CakeTime::format($this->request->data['Meeting']['date'], '%B %d, %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a virtual field in the Model to create the format you want, so the result is calculated via the sql rather than after the find.....

From the model:

`$this->virtualFields['date'] = 'DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d/%m/%Y")';`

From the Controller:

```
$this->Meeting->virtualFields['date'] = 'DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d/%m/%Y")';
```